# Printing in MVVM, using the viewmodel

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, printing

I have a C# WPF application, written using MVVM principles.

I would like to print a view, represented in a viewmodel. In order to do that, I have based myself on [this URL](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/mahesh/printing-in-wpf/), so I ended up with the following source code:

```
PrintDialog printDialog = new PrintDialog();
if (printDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    FlowDocument doc = new FlowDocument(new Paragraph(new Run("Some text goes here")));
    doc.Name = "FlowDoc";
    doc.DataContext = this;
    // Create a DocumentPaginator for the FlowDocument content
    DocumentPaginator paginator = ((IDocumentPaginatorSource)doc).DocumentPaginator;
    // Set the printer and print the document
    printDialog.PrintDocument(paginator, "Printing Example");
}
```

This piece of source contains two problems:

1. I cannot simply add the viewmodel as a datacontext of the FlowDocument and expecting to work. Can I?
2. ... but the first issue: apparently the `printDialog` object does not even have a `PrintDocument()` method.

As far as the first question is concerned: the mentioned hyperlink provides with some examples of adding sections, paragraphs, ... to the `FlowDocument`.

But does anybody know how to perform the actual printing?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You are likely referencing the Winforns type (wrong namespace). Ensure that you are referencing `System.Windows.Controls.PrintDialog`. And because your are emphasizing the MVVM compliance of your implementation I have to add that your solution is a clear violation of MVVM as the pattern does not allow to handle controls, or UI elements and UI logic in general, outside the View component. Additionally, MVVM is not a principle but a design pattern. This is a big difference.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.printdialog.printdocument?view=windowsdesktop-7.0#system-windows-controls-printdialog-printdocument(system-windows-documents-documentpaginator-system-string)

Comment: @BionicCode: a wrong namespace, that's how simple programming problems can be. Thanks for your quick reply. You can add this as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: Keep in mind only the Text property of the Run can use binding, so, yes you can add the ViewModel to the DataContext to a degree, but in my experience this isn't enough and you really end up using code behind.