# Why is my document, printed using a printDialog, split in two columns?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, layout, printing

I'm setting my first steps in MVVM WPF printing of documents, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77785180).

Now my code, more or less, looks as follows:

```
if (printDialog.ShowDialog() == true)
{
    FlowDocument doc = new FlowDocument(new Paragraph(new Run($"Print Document ({DateTime.Now.ToString("F")})")));
    doc.Name = "FlowDoc";
    doc.PagePadding = new System.Windows.Thickness(40);
    Paragraph par_ActieveMatrijsPalletten  = new Paragraph(new Run("Sectie active relevant_objects"));
    Paragraph par_Geplanderelevant_objects = new Paragraph(new Run("Sectie planned relevant_objects"));
    System.Windows.Documents.Table tbl_Actieverelevant_objects = new Table();
    tbl_Actieverelevant_objects.Columns.Add(new TableColumn() { Name = "Field1", Width = GridLength.Auto });
    ...
    tbl_Activerelevant_objects.RowGroups.Add(new TableRowGroup());
    foreach (var element in Activerelevant_objects)
    {
        TableRow currentRow = new TableRow();
        currentRow.Cells.Add(new TableCell(new Paragraph(new Run(element.Field1.ToString()))));
        ...
        tbl_Activerelevant_objects.RowGroups[0].Rows.Add(currentRow);
    }
    System.Windows.Documents.Table tbl_plannedrelevant_objects = new Table();
    tbl_plannedrelevant_objects.Columns.Add(new TableColumn() { Name = "Field1", Width = GridLength.Auto });
    ...
    tbl_plannedrelevant_objects.RowGroups.Add(new TableRowGroup());
    foreach (var element in plannedrelevant_objects)
    {
        TableRow currentRow = new TableRow();
        currentRow.Cells.Add(new TableCell(new Paragraph(new Run(element.Field1.ToString()))));
        ...
        tbl_plannedrelevant_objects.RowGroups[0].Rows.Add(currentRow);
    }
    doc.Blocks.Add(par_Activerelevant_objects);
    doc.Blocks.Add(tbl_Activerelevant_objects);
    doc.Blocks.Add(new Paragraph(new Run("END OF DOCUMENT")));
    // Create a DocumentPaginator for the FlowDocument content
    DocumentPaginator paginator = ((IDocumentPaginatorSource)doc).DocumentPaginator;
    // Set the printer and print the document
    printDialog.PrintDocument(paginator, "Printing Document");
}
```

This code still contains different issues:

1. The width of the `TableColumn`s is not correct (I ask for autofit to contents, it just uses some minimal value).
2. The gridlines are not visible.
3. The printer prints the document in "multiple-columns-style".

That third point is the major one: it's just as if the printer tries to print everything in two columns on one page. This is absolutely not what I want, but I have no idea which object causes this: is it the `printDialog` in some way, the paginator, the flowdocument?

Does anybody have an idea?

Thanks in advance

For a better understanding, my problem is that my document looks as shown in this image (the black arrows show the text direction, you can clearly see the two columns the document is made of):

[image]

Comment: Assuming you have a default printer, it does come with its own settings and preferences. Does it maybe have a page layout set?

Comment: @rene: thanks for the quick reply, but I just checked and the printer preferences are ok.

Comment: I found this question to be a duplicate.